# Why does docker overwrite everything I've installed?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've got a rails proxy app that runs with jupyter notebooks, and I'm trying to get a docker image up and running with supervisor as the entry point.

However, after including a FROM jupyter/notebook, everything I did to set up the rails is gone!

My dockerfile

```
#Installs Jupyter Notebook and IPython kernel from the current branch
# Another Docker container should inherit with `FROM jupyter/notebook`
# to run actual services.

# For RVM support - ultimately do out own solution here.
FROM tzenderman/docker-rvm:latest

# Update aptitude
RUN apt-get update

# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git supervisor libgmp3-dev

# Set up loggin for now
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor

# USING TOKENS ###################################################
ARG DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN

RUN git clone https://$DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN:x-oauth-basic@github.com/proversity-org/edx-api-jupyter.git /tmpapp/
RUN mkdir /home/sifu/
RUN cp -R /tmpapp/* /home/sifu/
RUN cp -R -r /tmpapp/. /home/sifu/
RUN chown root:root -R /home/sifu/

#################################################################

WORKDIR /home/sifu

# Install ruby using RVM
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install $(cat .ruby-version) --verify-downloads"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm use $(cat .ruby-version) --default"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm list"
RUN rvm requirements

# run docker env for ruby apps
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "source .docker-ruby-version"

RUN echo $RUBY-VERSION

ENV GEM_HOME /usr/local
ENV PATH /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:$PATH
ENV PATH /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:$PATH

# Install Bundler
RUN ruby --version
RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle config --global silence_root_warning 1

# Install Sifu gems
RUN bundle install --gemfile=/home/sifu/Gemfile

# Alow for arugments to sifu & notebook (server ip & port etc)

#RUN /bin/bash -l -c "which bundle"
#RUN /bin/bash -l -c "cp $(which ruby) /usr/bin/"

# Set up supervisor config -- move this up later
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# Set as environment variables

FROM jupyter/notebook

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/myapp/supervisord.conf"]
```

All the software I installed is gone, when I use a FROM jupyter/notebook to include the notebooks in the image.

Is there something crucial I am missing?

Comment: you have 2 `FROM` instructions

Comment: @user2915097 and that will overwrite the last FROM... I am such an idiot!

Comment: Yes, I proposed https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19644#issuecomment-174362191  but it was refused